# File sync solution with pattern matching

Tags: sync, rsync, dropbox, applescript

I have a directory I want to sync over the cloud using a service like `Dropbox`. But, within that folder, I only want to sync directories that match a particular pattern.

For instance, sync all folders except folders named `node_modules`.

Do you know of any way to do this? Here are some ideas I had, and their pitfalls:

1. Using any sync service, say, Dropbox, set up an AppleScript to watch changes in some directory on my computer. If the change is not in `node_modules`, push it over to the Dropbox folder location. **Issues**: Does not have two-way sync.
2. Solve the issue of #1 by utilizing `rsync` in some clever way. **Issues**: Race condition handling? I'm worried about two computers modifying the same file within too short a time frame, and `rsync` freaking out.

Have you dealt with this issue before? What's your solution?

**To clarify**, this isn't about excluding a single, or even a finite number of directories. I want to exclude **any and all** directories/files that match a given pattern, wherever they may be in the folder. So I might have 1000 `node_modules` directories within my synced directory, and they are all excluded.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/help/175/en

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/469776/how-to-exclude-filesnot-folders-from-dropbox-sync

Comment: Thanks for the response, @techie007, but there are `n` folders named `node_modules`, and they aren't necessarily in the root directory. It needs to know to exclude **any and all** `node_modules` directories and subdirs, not any given one.

Answer (score 2):

Install a software called [syncback](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/)

**1** - Create a `New Profile`

**2** - Choose `Synchronize`

**3** - Click on `Change Filter`

[image]

**4** - Click to `Add` a folder NOT to copy

**5** - Type `*\node_modules\`

(Click on help to see advanced rules for filters, very important!)

[image]

**6** - Confirm that changes will work (Created a test folder to try out rules)

[image]

Click Ok.

Enjoy!

Comment: This is the sketchiest looking software I've ever seen. But it just might work. I'll take a closer look at it over the weekend. I really appreciate the thoroughness with which you responded – thanks for that. Awww shucks, Windows only! I'm on OSX. But I'm glad to see that solutions *do* exist...

Comment: Np. It's a shame it work for you, hopefully for someone else though.