# Is there a way to ignore/exclude subfolders from syncing on Dropbox (for Mac OS X)?

Tags: macos, mac, dropbox

Context: I'm trying to sync my entire Mac home folder into Dropbox. I moved Dropbox into the root folder, and sym-linked the home folder into Dropbox. The problem is that `~/Library/Containers` consists of tons of sym-links which serve to duplicate data a lot for Dropbox (which follows sym-links as though they weren't links). I would like to tell Dropbox to ignore `/Dropbox/home-sym-link/Library/Containers`.

I have searched for this quite a bit. Here is what I have found:

1. Selective Sync. This feature is similar to what I want, but actually the opposite of what I need (I think). Selective Sync allows me to tell Dropbox to prevent certain folders in the Dropbox servers from syncing/downloading to my computer client. What I want to do is the opposite: tell Dropbox to prevent certain folders on my computer from syncing/uploading onto Dropbox's servers.
2. CLI. It appears that Linux has a CLI for accessing Dropbox, which has an exclude command. I have not found this to exist on Mac OS X, but would love to be proved wrong.
3. `.dropboxignore`. I've seen a lot of users requesting a `.gitignore-like` file format for specifying regexes and the like to be ignored by Dropbox. Again, this would probably work, but does not seem to exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exclude files(not folders) from dropbox sync?](http://superuser.com/questions/469776/how-to-exclude-filesnot-folders-from-dropbox-sync)

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe, since this is asking about folders, where the referenced question is explicitly about files (not folders).  But, it's a good reference item.

Comment: Thanks @ Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 . The file solution in that question does also work for folders. Good find.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox doesn't seem to be able to parse Mac "aliases", which normally work like sym-links.  So, if you're syncing a folder called `Library` and it has a child folder called `Containers`, can you move `Containers` somewhere else on your filesystem, and then place an "alias" of it back in `Library`?  This will allow you (in the Finder) to visit the `Containers` folder like normal, but Dropbox should ignore it (actually, I think it will sync a small file representing the alias, but it won't follow the alias and sync the dir contents).

One problem with this might be whatever other SW is using the `Containers` folder.  If that SW is trying to follow a UNIX-like path to `Containers`, that SW will see a "file" called `Containers".  Only alias-aware SW will be able to follow through to the real sub-folder.

So, the same thing that helps keep Dropbox from syncing this folder may prevent other SW from using it properly too.  It will be transparent to a user in the Finder, though.