# How do I exclude/ignore folder inside of Dropbox folder without selective sync?

Tags: sync, dropbox

I'm using [Dropbox](https://db.tt/2MTJooG) with some project and one of my directories has subdirectory it's called `~/Dropbox/stuff/data`, how do I exclude and/or ignore it without selective sync?

Comment: [some of this might be useful](http://superuser.com/questions/469776/how-to-exclude-files-not-folders-from-dropbox-sync)

Comment: But also, no they've shot down the `.gitignore` type of solution for a while.

Comment: I've recently implemented [dropboxignore](https://github.com/sp1thas/dropboxignore) which is a simple shell scripts that ignores files using file patterns and already existing `.gitignore` files. Hope to find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [announcement](https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/restore-delete/ignored-files), Dropbox allows user to ignore specific files. Based on your os, you can ignore files using one of the following commands:

Mac:

```
xattr -w com.dropbox.ignored 1 /Users/yourname/Dropbox\ \(Personal\)/YourFileName.pdf
```

Windows:

```
Set-Content -Path 'C:\Users\yourname\Dropbox(Personal)\YourFileName.pdf' -Stream com.dropbox.ignored -Value 1
```

Linux:

```
attr -s com.dropbox.ignored -V 1 /Users/yourname/Dropbox\ \(Personal\)/YourFileName.pdf
```

Comment: That Windows 'command' is PowerShell input, so it should be `powershell -command "Set-Content -Path \"<path>\" -Stream com.dropbox.ignored -Value 1"` for usage in batch scripts and `cmd`. For current folder, `<path>` := `%CD%` can be used.